# PN5122W Stylus pen Ubuntu

Tags: 23.10, stylus

My PN5122W stylus connects to my XPS 13 2 1 via Bluetooth; however, I am not sure how I can edit its functionality (pressure, action bottom, etc.). It does not show up in the Wacom stylus (as it is not Wacom, I guess).

Any help is appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 23.10 on XPS 13 2 in 1 9315.

Comment: I also use an XPS 13 inch 2-in-1 tablet PC with its Dell stylus.  I found the Stylus was not configurable under Linux, so I just left Windows on that system.  Granted, I have a daily Linux driver laptop that's twice as powerful (XPS 15 inch from 3 years ago that still outclasses anything i've used at work that aren't servers), but I don't know if Dell has a configuration option for their tablet PCs' tablets in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The stylus works with Xournal++ as one of the apps I use. It also works as a pointing device on Inspiron 7430.  Problem I have encountered is there is no software to map the 2 buttons.  So I have to select the writer/eraser option from the toolbar in the app as a workaround